# Bittrex Bot buy at ask

Tags: bots, bittrex

I am trying to write a bot to use it on Bittrex with nodeJs, but the documentation is very poor. My problem is that I would like to be able to buy the last ask, like when in the web you click in bid the option ask, this way the buy is instant.
For developing the bot I am using:
 https://github.com/n0mad01/node.bittrex.api
I have tried:

```
 bittrex.buyLimit({ market: 'BTC-ETH', quantity: 0.001, rate: "ask"}, function (data) {
    console.log("Response: " +data);
})
```

but it does not accept the rate "ask", is there any way this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Bittrex [api page](https://bittrex.com/home/api).

The *buyLimit* endpoint says that the *rate* must be **the rate at which to place the order**.

In order to get the current ask price, use the *getticker* api which will return something like:

```
{
    "success" : true,
    "message" : "",
    "result" : {
        "Bid" : 2.05670368,
        "Ask" : 3.35579531,
        "Last" : 3.35579531
    }
}
```

Comment: From my tests, I believe there is a delay between the ticker API and the price displayed on the website interface. Did you experienced it ?

Comment: @jbaptiste you can use websockets nowadays !